# HtmlEncode on Post for ASP.Net MVC 3 Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-encode

I have an ASP.Net MVC 3 page in which I have an Html.TextAreaFor control, see code below.  If I try to submit the page to the http post action with text in angle brackets like: `<test>`, I get a yellow error screen saying:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (RequestText="").

I don't understand why I am getting this because I found [an article by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) that says the new `<%: %>` syntax in .Net 4, will automatically HtmlEncode the element.  Since I'm using the <%: %> syntax for the Html.TextAreaFor control, I thought it would automatically take care of this and convert the angle brackets to the proper "&lt"; and "&gt" strings.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
    <h2>Enter a description of the support needed</h2>
    <%: Html.TextAreaFor( m => m.RequestText, 4, 90, null) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically right now, you're encoding the content of the `TextAreaFor` on the **output**. This doesn't help you in the slightest since you're trying to deal with **input**

If you want to submit "potentially dangerous" content, you need to either

1) decorate the `RequestText` property within your ViewModel with `[AllowHtml]`. (preferred)

```
[AllowHtml]
public string RequestText { get; set; }
```

2) disable `validateRequest`

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Then you **must** ensure you're appropriately sanitizing that data and/or encoding it in your controller before submitting it to your Repository Layer or Database.

Comment: Chase - I would rather not use the [AllowHtml], is there not a way to have the .net framework html encode the text for me when I post back to the controller action?

Comment: You encode it manually at the controller. It's the data layer that you don't want ton post unencoded data to. You have to handle this at the controller level.

Comment: Basically, HTML cannot encode data for you. You can use Javascript, but that's bad simply because they can just disable JS. The only sure fire way to do this is at the Server level and not the client level.

Answer (score 6):

You could decorate your `RequestText` property on the view model with the [`AllowHtmlAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute.aspx):

```
[AllowHtml]
public string RequestText { get; set; }
```

This way you are authorizing the client to submit HTML for this property only.

As far as the `<%: %>` syntax is concerned, this is used to HTML encode some value before outputting it to the page. It is used to protect against XSS attacks. It is irrelevant in your case because you are not outputting to the page, you are receiving HTML characters in a request.

Comment: Do we need to use `@Html.Raw(model.RequestText)`? or internal MVC framework will take care while rendering?

Comment: If i right AllowHtml attribute does not allow <a> to be exist in html text. Do you have an idea?