# Send HTML data to Controller ASP .NET MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to send data as Html to controller and save in database. I try to send data as html but I failed.

Here is code

```
$("#savechanges").click(function () {
        $("#notify").val($("#notify_to").val());

        //here I want to send html to controller
        $("#editor").val($("input[name='" + "Editor2" + "']").val());

        $("#nid").val($(".notifybox").attr('id'));
        $("#form_editing").submit();
    });
```

When I click save button then this error shows

[image]

What can I do to fix this problem

Comment: Another potential solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808910/htmlencode-on-post-for-asp-net-mvc-3-html-textareafor   Use the `[AllowHtml]` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

In your post method of the following controller just add

```
<pre>
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "requestValidationMode=2.0" in your .config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

For more details: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)